# Which sentence is correct? (as well as)

Tags: grammar, adverbs, gerunds, grammaticality-in-context

I want to know which is the correct use of `as well as` structure:

```
The devices have more security than before as well as mitigate their risks
The devices have more security than before as well as mitigating their risks
```

I think the former is correct, because: `The devices mitigate their risks`, but my teacher told me the latter is correct.

Comment: Neither is very good, stylistically, if only because the complement of **as well as** is a result of the first predicate, making **as well as** the wrong choice. It's like saying "The farmer planted more acreage as well as producing a larger crop."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://site.uit.no/english/grammar/aswellas/) source:

When we put a verb after as well as, we use the -ing form of the verb.

> Running is healthy as well as making you feel good.
>
> He broke the window, as well as destroying the wall.
>
> She draws as well as designing clothes.

You can also check [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132087/as-well-as-verb-ing) out. The same question was asked before on ELU.